# ¿Como insertar un color predeterminado en una tab en tabLayout Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación Android y he creado un tabLayout donde hay 3 tab, y me gustaría que la tab central tuviera un color distinto, tipo Instagram en la primera versión. No logro la manera de conseguirlo. Gracias.

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());

 int[] tabIcons = {
                R.drawable.ic_home_menu,
                R.drawable.ic_publish_menu,
                R.drawable.ic_profile_menu,
        };

  tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]); //Cambiar el color de la TAB
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo? es dificil ayudarte sin ver que has intentado hacer

Comment: El color del indicador predeterminado se toma de la AppTheme. Mira este enlace como referencia - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904138/how-to-change-the-new-tablayout-indicator-color-and-height

Comment: Allí lo tienes. Ahora como hago para indicarle un color de fondo a la tab central.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor sería crear una vista personalizada y asignarla al Tab en la posición que deseas de tu TabLayout. Tomando como referencia tu ejemplo:

```
TabLayout.Tab centerTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout_red, null);
centerTab.setCustomView(view);
```

Adicionalmente debes agregar las siguientes propiedades a tu **TabLayout** en el xml para eliminar el padding entre tabs.

```
app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
```

A continuación los recursos que utilicé para el ejemplo

tab_layout_red.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="15dip"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_red_indicator">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_red_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:text="Tab Custom"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

tab_red_indicador.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
</selector>
```

tab_selected.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#F44336" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-3dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:left="10dp"
                android:top="15dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="15dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#B71C1C" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Cabe destacar que ésta es una implementación estática para un tab en especial.

Comment: Muy bueno, solo me faltaría saber como hago para que se muestra el icono, ya que si le añado la imagen tab_layout_red.xml, no se ve con el mismo tamaño que los otros.

Comment: Si asignándole un ícono al objeto **Tab** no te complace tienes como opción agregar en el **TextView[@id/tab_red_title]** un Drawable en alguno de los bordes. Sino un **ImageView** a un lado del **TextView**, con ésta opción podrías manejar el tamaño y ubicación del ícono a tu gusto y dejando el parámetro _android:orientation="horizontal"_ en el **LinearLayout** del archivo tab_layout_red.xml dado el caso que quieras ubicarlo a uno de los lados del **TextView**.

Comment: ya lo intente, sigue estando mas pequeño que los otros.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi, cambia el color que desees.

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getCustomView()
                        .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Ese error aparece porque getCustomView devuelve null, no estas seteando un layout diferente para cada tab?

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo esta [librería](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) en la que te permite cambiar el color de los tabs de forma bastante cómoda

```
tabs.setIndicatorColorResource(R.color.morado);
```